# как записать (в переменную) что пользователь написал боту в телеграмме в питон

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

вот часть кода

```
def devs(message: types.Message ):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Что вы хотите купить',parse_mode='html')
```

нужно что при запросе кто покупки пользователь писал что хочет (и записывал это в переменную)а другой при запросе получал ответ

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать создать функцию для обработки событий:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def handle_message(call):
    if call.message:
        message = call.data
```

В переменную `message` должен попасть ответ юзера. Минус в том, что такая функция хэндлер будет обрабатывать вообще все сообщения юзера